# Selecionar 1 registro de cada ID baseado na ultima data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela ficticia TB_META com os campos:

```
COD_VENDEDOR | DAT_ATIVACAO | VAL_META
```

Supondo que tenho esses valores na tabela:

```
1 | 2011-01-01 | 1
1 | 2014-04-04 | 2
2 | 2012-01-01 | 3
2 | 2013-03-03 | 4
3 | 2013-01-01 | 5
3 | 2014-04-04 | 6
```

Quero pegar apenas um registro de cada ID. Esse registro sera pego baseado na data mais atual do id, gerando esse resultado

```
1 | 2014-04-04 | 2
2 | 2013-03-03 | 4
3 | 2014-04-04 | 6
```

Minha tentativa ficou assim, mas acho q nao da pra aproveitar nada disso:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TQ.[COD_VENDEDOR]
                        ,TQ.[VAL_META]
                        ,TQ.[DAT_ATIVACAO]
                    FROM 
                        [dbo].[TB_META] TQ
                    INNER JOIN
                        [dbo].[TB_VENDEDOR] TV
                        ON TQ.COD_VENDEDOR = TV.COD_VENDEDOR
                    WHERE 
                        TQ.DAT_ATIVACAO = (SELECT TOP 1 DAT_ATIVACAO FROM TB_META WHERE COD_VENDEDOR = TQ.COD_VENDEDOR ORDER BY DAT_ATIVACAO)
```

Answer (score 6):

Alterando um pouco seu *subselect* você chega facilmente ao resultado desejado:

```
SELECT TQ.[COD_VENDEDOR], TQ.[VAL_META], TQ.[DAT_ATIVACAO]
                FROM 
                    [dbo].[TB_META] TQ
                WHERE 
                    TQ.DAT_ATIVACAO = (SELECT MAX(DAT_ATIVACAO) 
                                       FROM TB_META 
                                       WHERE COD_VENDEDOR = TQ.COD_VENDEDOR 
                                       GROUP BY DAT_ATIVACAO)
```

Retirei a tabela `TB_VENDEDOR` porque ela não influencia na resposta, mas se quiser recolocar o `INNER JOIN`, é só editar a resposta.

Comment: Sugiro que retire o `GROUP BY DAT_ATIVACAO` da subconsulta, pois colunas que estão em uso nas funções de agregação não fazem parte da cláusula GROUP BY.  Nessa subconsulta correlacionada não é necessária a cláusula GROUP BY pois serão lidas somente as linhas de um único vendedor, por chamada.

Answer (score 1):

Desculpem-me mas está com erro o código acima:

O correto seria:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(TQ.[COD_VENDEDOR]), TQ.[VAL_META], TQ.[DAT_ATIVACAO]
            FROM 
                [dbo].[TB_META] TQ
            WHERE 
                TQ.DAT_ATIVACAO = (SELECT MAX(DAT_ATIVACAO) 
                                   FROM TB_META 
                                   WHERE COD_VENDEDOR = TQ.COD_VENDEDOR 
                                   GROUP BY COD_VENDEDOR)
```

Comment: Paulo, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Poderia explicar melhor como sua resposta resolve o problema, apontando o que foi corrigido? Você pode [edit] sua pergunta. Recomendo também a leitura do [tour] e [help].

Comment: "acima" aqui é relativo, Paulo, as respostas podem estar listadas de 3 maneiras (vide tabs no topo justo abaixo da pergunta). Realmente, você precisa explicar melhor do que está falando ;)

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a lógica que você fez, é só ordenar decrescentemente assim: `ORDER BY DAT_ATIVACAO DESC`